# How is the length of the projection onto a subspace distributed?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, projective-geometry, projection

Let $B$ be the unit sphere of an M-dimensional linear space and let $x$ be uniformly distributed on $B$. Let $A$ be an N-dimensional subspace of the said linear space (N<M). How is the projection of $x$ onto $A$, i.e. $P_Ax$, distributed? Specifically, how is the length of this projection, i.e. $\sqrt{x^{'}P_A^{'}P_Ax}$, distributed?

I can quite easily solve this problem for low dimensions (e.g. M=2, N=1), but I am looking for the general rule here. I can also simulate the distribution of $x$, and therefore that of $P_Ax$, but I would prefer an exact solution.

**Special**: If someone can present an exact solution, that can be rewarded by a co-authorship in a scientific publication. I am not a mathematician, but I am working on a field where mathematics is frequently encountered.

Comment: Do we agree that it's the unit sphere, not the unit ball ?

Comment: See through Euclidproject "The General Projected Normal Distribution of Arbitrary Dimension: Modeling and Bayesian
Inference" Daniel Hernandez-Stumpfhauser, F. Jay Breidt, and Mark J. van der Woerd

Comment: The Hernandez-Stumpfhauser paper is related to my question but does not solve it. The guys in that paper note that you can project a general normal distribution onto a sphere, and indeed, as has been known before, you can generate my vector x by projecting a spherical normal variable on the unit sphere.

My question is about further projecting this vector x onto a linear subspace. For example, you can think of M=3 and N=2, so that you have a vector distributed on a usual sphere, and you project it on a plane.